# Updating fields in OOP

Tags: java, oop

I've a question about object oriented in java.

[Class Diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OVMEQ.png)

I create a method kick and hit based on class diagram and I make two object Sub-zero and rizen.

I have a case study when rizen kicks sub-zero, lifepoint sub-zero should decrease as much as attackhit rizen, but my code instead lifepoint sub-zero decreases as attackhit sub-zero.

```
public class GameCharacter {
String name;
int lifePoint=100;
int attackHitPoint;
int attackKickPoint;


public GameCharacter (String name,int attackHitPoint, int attackKickPoint){
    this.name=name;
    this.attackHitPoint=attackHitPoint;
    this.attackKickPoint=attackKickPoint;
}

public void hit (GameCharacter karB){
    lifePoint-=attackHitPoint;
}

public void kick (GameCharacter karB){
    lifePoint-=attackKickPoint;
}

public int getLifePoint() {
    return lifePoint;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public static void main (String[] args){
    GameCharacter rizen = new GameCharacter("rizen",10 ,20);
    GameCharacter subzero = new GameCharacter("zub-zero", 5,25);
    rizen.kick(subzero);
    System.out.println(subzero.getLifePoint());
   }

}
```

Comment: If character A kicks B, you have to decrement the lifepoint of B not A.

Therefore, the main task is to modify the kick method so that it increments the attackkickpoint of the character in focus and at the same time, decrements the lifepoint of the other character.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
public void kick (GameCharacter karB){
    lifePoint-=attackKickPoint;
}
```

This is the same as if you had

```
    this.lifePoint -= attackKickPoint;
```

When you call this method with `rizen.kick(subzero)`, `this` is `rizen`, and `karB` is `subzero`. So `karB` is the one whose `lifePoint` you need to update.

```
    karB.lifePoint -= attackKickPoint;
```

Answer (score 0):

In your code, there is no interaction between the current object `this` and the object `karB` that you pass to `hit()` and `kick()`. You need to link them up, i.e. call a method on the other object or use its properties.

Have a look at this code, for example:

```
public void hit (GameCharacter karB){
    this.lifePoint -= karB.attackHitPoint;
}

public void kick (GameCharacter karB){
    karB.hit(this);
}
```

In `hit()`, you will now decrease the `lifePoint` of the current object by the `attackHitPoint` of the other object `karB` now. Same applies to `kick()`, where we now link both objects up and tell Java to make `karB` get hit by the current character `this`.